# python pandas resample count and sum

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have data by date and want to create a new dataframe by week with sum of sales and count of categories.

```
#standard packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#visualization
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#create weekly datetime index
edf = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\j~\raw.csv', parse_dates=[6])
edf2 = edf[['DATESENT','Sales','Category']].copy()
edf2

#output

DATESENT    |  SALES  | CATEGORY
2014-01-04      100        A
2014-01-05      150        B
2014-01-07      150        C
2014-01-10      175        D

#create datetime index of week
edf2['DATESENT']=pd.to_datetime(edf2['DATESENT'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
edf2 = edf2.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(edf2['DATESENT']))
edf2.resample('w').sum()
edf2

#output

            SALES CATEGORY 
DATESENT     
2014-01-05  250      AB
2014-01-12  325      CD
```

But I am looking for

```
           SALES CATEGORY 
DATESENT     
2014-01-05  250      2
2014-01-12  325      2
```

This didn't work ...

```
edf2 = e2.resample('W').agg("Category":len,"Sales":np.sum)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Agg takes a dictionary as arguments in [various formats](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns).

```
edf2 = e2.resample('W').agg({"Category":'size',"Sales":'sum'})
```

Comment: Also a great answer +1

Comment: Thanks, I am learning from you piRSquared.  I do like TimeGrouper better that resample in general.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there a way to do size but distinct? So if there is category A twice, it will be counted once?

Comment: Yes, you can change size out for 'nunique'. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thank You! Both answers worked great, trying to figure out, if I can accept both

Answer (score 2):

using `pd.TimeGrouper` + `agg`

```
f = {'SALES': 'sum', 'CATEGORY': 'count'}
g = pd.TimeGrouper('W')
df.set_index('DATESENT').groupby(g).agg(f)

            CATEGORY  SALES
DATESENT                   
2014-01-05         2    250
2014-01-12         2    325
```

Comment: What is the advantage of TimeGrouper over resample? I need to use this data for a time series prediction, will I be able to use it with TImegrouper? Is there a way to do a distinct count of category? Thank You

Comment: @jeangelj No real obvious advantage of using TimeGrouper.  Yes! to get number of unique values, replace `'count'` with `'nunique'`

Comment: Thank You! Both answers worked great, trying to figure out, if I can accept both

Comment: @jeangelj no, you cannot.  You can upvote both!... choose the answer you feel was the most helpful and if you still can't decide then accept ScottBoston's answer

Comment: thank you @piRSquared, you help me every second day, so i will definitely add you a lot of rep points soon (I promise) - I upvoted both - thank you very much for all your help, it's invaluable